# Windows. How to add PermGen space?

Tags: java, windows, permgen

How to add PermGen space for jvm in windows?
I found many link about it? but I don't understand where I must click and write new value

Comment: Are you starting your Java program from the command line / via icon or from within an IDE, e.g. eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase size of PermGen Space by using JVM param `-XX:MaxPermSize and -XX:PermSize.`

[image]

Comment: Where I can find this parameters?

Comment: @user2645679 You won't find them anywhere. You have to _define_ them. Java is not Windows where you can simply open up some UI and edit some configuration parameter. It is designed to be platform independent.

Comment: @user2645679 they are JVM arguments. Provided snapshot of the same(my IDEA IDE) in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is more of a Java runtime (JVM) setting than a Windows one. You configure it by adding the below parameters (example only) to your Java command line.

```
-XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

For example, if you were doing `java -jar someapp.jar`, you might have to do `java -jar someapp.jar -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`.

A common practice is to define the `-X` parameters in an environment variable called `JAVA_OPTS` and using it in the command lines.

On unix,

`export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"`

`java $JAVA_OPTS -jar someapp.jar`

On Windows,

you can define a Local / System variable similarly.

`java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar someapp.jar`

Comment: The `%JAVA_OPTS%` need to go **before*  the `-jar` option, otherwise they are simply passed to the main class as a commandline argument, not to the JVM

Comment: if I start my application from eclipse, how can do it?

Comment: The principle is the same. The JVM has to get to it when you launch your program. See the screenshot in @Aniket's answer on how to do it.