# Getting 'permgen error' while deploying war file on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jboss

When I deployed and I have received 'permgen' error for my JSF Web application.

Detail are : JBOSS AS 7, jvm: Oracle JRE 1.7, OS: Amazon Linux 32-bit, 1.7 GB RAM.

Exception is :
javax.servlet.ServletException : PermGen space
          javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
...

Comment: Sounds to me like you use up perm gen space. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143155/windows-how-to-add-permgen-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss seems doesn't have enough permgen space to load java classes. Look at this page about PermGen https://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-permgen-leak

I presume it is standalone Jboss, to solve that problem, edit standalone configuration: $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf

Find this line:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

Increase -XX:MaxPermSize value, eg.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Then stop, and restart JBoss.